# How can I get custom field data from the Asana API?

Tags: asana

I've configured some custom fields for a project in Asana. How can I fetch those fields when getting tasks from the Asana API?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of custom fields by fetching the task object directly:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal_access_token>" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/1001
```

Or by adding `custom_fields` to the `opt_fields` parameter for a request which returns compact representations of tasks:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal_access_token>" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1331/tasks?opt_fields=custom_fields
```